# Networking between docker containers

Tags: networking, docker

I'm converting my applications into containers and I'm having a hard time getting two containers to communicate with each other over the host's interface.

Configuration wise, each of my applications are set up this way:

```
app1: Listens for incoming socket connections on 127.0.0.1:4444
app2: Connects to the socket server on 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Docker wise I am starting my applications this way:

```
docker run -p 4444:4444 -itd --name app1 app1
docker run -itd --name app2 app2
```

app2 is failing to connect to app1. I've hit a wall. How do I debug this?

**EDIT:**

Looks like 127.0.0.1 inside the containers is not the right way to go. This will bind the server/client to lo interface instead of the bridged interface with the host.

Instead, docker can do some automatic DNS based on --name by creating a new docker network:

```
# docker network create myapp
# docker run --network myapp -p 4444:4444 -itd --name app1 app1
# docker run --network myapp -itd --name app2 app2
```

And inside the docker containers, instead of binding and connecting to 127.0.0.1, the server binds to app1:4444 and the client connects to app1:4444. The hostname will resolve to the bridged IP assigned by docker.

**Problem:**
Although now I can see the IPs resolving correctly, the connections eventually timeout.

Comment: When you need several containers working together, use `docker-compose`, it will handle the naming/networking for you.

Comment: Super User is the wrong Stack Exchange to ask this question. Questions surveying Docker BKMs are best asked at Stack Overflow. There are several questions answered there offering different ways to network between containers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35184695/977939